# Large number of smaller parts of a parquet file slowing down read operation and processing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, parquet

I have a parquet file which gets some records appended daily. Each day a new part file(of the order of few KBs in size) gets added to the parquet making it a large number of smaller part files now. This has lead to slow reads and processing of the parquet in downstream Spark jobs.

I want to know if there is any standard way to treat this other than periodically reading the whole dataset and rewriting as a fewer partition parquet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

look at the option of using delta, this will improve query operation as the transaction log is used, amongst other things like statistics, to identify the parts.

No idea if you are on azure from the above, but if so that is particularly bad for lots of partitions / small files and the scan will take place before any partition information is used.